# Convert Mp3 to WAV with naudio without writing on disk. (Stream only)

Tags: c#, mp3, wav, naudio

I want to convert mp3 files to WAV. In DirectX.DirectSound the secondary buffer is supporting only WAV. I am converting the files using naudio and this is working fine.

```
using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(mp3File))
{
    WaveFileWriter.CreateWaveFile(outputFile, reader);
}
```

The problem is that I can't save the files on disk so I have to use them with stream.

```
 Mp3FileReader mp3reader = new Mp3FileReader(filenamePathMp3);
 var stream=WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(mp3reader);
```

which throws an exception Value does not fall within the expected range. How Can I make a stream with the audio converted to WAV or Raw audio for the secondaryBuffer without writing on disk?

Thank you in advance,

Answer (score 4):

`WaveFileWriter` can write to a `Stream` instead of a file so you can just pass in a `MemoryStream`. Also, `Mp3FileReader.Read` already returns PCM so you could read out into a `byte[]` and then insert that into your memory stream if you prefer.

Comment: Health This is my code but I am getting the same error

` long count;

byte[] info ;
using (Mp3FileReader mp3reader = new Mp3FileReader(filenamePathMp3))
    
{
               
count = mp3reader.Length;
               
info = new byte[count];
               
mp3reader.Read(info, 0, (int)count);
            
}
            
MemoryStream memstream = new MemoryStream(info);
            
foreGroundSound = new SecondaryBuffer(source: memstream, desc: bufferDescription, parent: sounddevice);
`
Any ideas? thank you in advance.

Comment: Will `Mp3FileReader.Read` read whole file or only audio data samples? I want to make a FadeOut and I consider multiplying byes by some value. Will that work? Will I be able to generate new mp3 from result array?

Answer (score 4):

I've achieved to convert MP3 to WAV without writing it to the disk by using `MemoryStream` and `WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream`
You can also set up sampleRate bitrate and channel using `RawSourceWaveStream`

```cs
public static byte[] ConvertMp3ToWav(byte[] mp3File)
{
    using (var retMs = new MemoryStream())
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(mp3File))
    using (Mp3FileReader reader = new Mp3FileReader(ms))
    {
        var rs = new RawSourceWaveStream(reader, new WaveFormat(16000, 1));
        using (WaveStream pcmStream = WaveFormatConversionStream.CreatePcmStream(rs))
        {
            WaveFileWriter.WriteWavFileToStream(retMs,pcmStream);
            return retMs.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```